# JW Player - Error loading player: HTML5 player not found in Rails 3.2 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have the licensed version of JW Player 6. I downloaded the files and put them in the assets/javascript directory. Aside from the skins directory, there is a JS file for the HTML5 player as well as a flash.swf file for the flash player. Everything that I've done thus far has worked locally but as soon as I push to Heroku I get errors.

First attempt:

In my `application.js` file:

```
...
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer.html5 # the file name is jwplayer.html5.js
...
```

After running `rake assets:clean ; rake assets:precompile` I get the following error in the view (on Heroku):

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in nodes#show:
jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js isn't precompiled
```

---

Second attempt:

In my `application.js` file:

```
...
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer
...
```

Then, I added this to the `production.rb` environment config file:

```
# Also tried %w(jwplayer.html5.js)
config.assets.precompile += %w(jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js)
```

After cleaning and precompiling the assets and pushing to Heroku, the original `ActionView::Template::Error` was no longer happening, but now the JW Player displays this message:

```
Error loading player: HTML5 player not found
```

---

This is the JW Player initialization in the HAML view:

```
:javascript
  jwplayer("video_display_object_#{display_object.id}").setup({
    width: "948",
    height: "533",
    image: "#{display_object.video_screenshot_url}",
    file: "#{display_object.resource_url}",
    modes: [
        { type: 'flash',
          src: "#{asset_path('jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf')}",
          config: {
            skin: "#{asset_path('jwplayer/skins/beelden.xml')}",
            'controlbar.position': 'over',
            'controlbar.idlehide': 'true'
          }
        },
        // I've also tried "#{javascript_path('jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js}"
        // And "/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js"
        { type: 'html5', src: "#{asset_path('jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js')}" }
    ]
  });
```

I don't really know what to do at this point. Like I mentioned earlier, everything works locally, just not on Heroku.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put up an example that can be debugged if possible?

Comment: This is all my company's code so it's not easy getting an example up unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, too bad, I would have liked to see something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was quite frustrating, but we managed to get it up and running. The solution is actually quite simple (once you know what to do):

If you decide NOT to use the cloud-hosted JW Player (which is quite easy to set up since the asset pipeline is not involved), download and unzip the `jwplayer` folder.

Drop the extracted `jwplayer` folder into your Rails app's `/app/assets/javascripts` folder.

Add the following to your `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer.html5
```

Run `rake assets:precompile`.

To get the player up and running in a view, use the piece of (HAML) code below. (Additional options are available [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference).)

```
%div{id: 'video'} Loading the player...
:javascript
  jwplayer('video').setup({
    file: 'INSERT_VIDEO_FILE_PATH_HERE',
    flashplayer: "#{asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')}",
    html5player: "#{asset_path('jwplayer.html5.js')}"
  });
```

It's essential you specify the `flashplayer` and `html5player` attributes (in case you want to support both versions of the player).

Customize away!

Comment: I had to remove "modes" from my jwplayer setup but this worked. Thanks!